# Convert LINESTRING wkt representation LINESTRING((a b),(c d)) to LineString[(a,b),(c,d)]

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I know how to go from

```
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
```

to

```
LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))
```

But not the other way around. How do I do this?

The reason I need to do this is that I want to be able to apply the following function to split my LINESTRINGS into it sides.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing

def segments(curve):
    return list(map(LineString, zip(curve.coords[:-1], curve.coords[1:])))


line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])

line_segments = segments(line)
for segment in line_segments:
    print(segment)
```

and it cannot be applied to wkt representations of linestrings.

Comment: `LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))` is the string wkt encoding of the python object in the first line of your question, right? Are you asking how to convert from a wkt string to a shapely linestring?

Comment: If not, it's not clear what it is you're trying to do and where you're stuck. Please clarify in python what you are doing now, what's not working, and what you're trying to do, ideally as a [MRE]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))'` is not a valid WKT strings. For your example the correct representation should be `'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'` without inner parentheses.

To convert from a format to another, use `dumps/loads` from `shapely.wkt` module:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import shapely.wkt

line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
str_line = shapely.wkt.dumps(line)

print(shapely.wkt.loads(str_line) == line)

# Output:
True
```

**Update**: if you want to parse a such string, use a regex to remove inner parentheses:

```
s = 'LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))'
str_line = re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', r'\1', s)

print(shapely.wkt.loads(str_line) == line)

# Output:
True
```

**Update 2**: This doesn't work?

```
import pandas as pd
import shapely.wkt

df = pd.DataFrame({'lines': ['LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)']})
df['lines2'] = df['lines'].apply(lambda x: shapely.wkt.loads(x))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                        lines                      lines2
0  LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)  LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)

>>> df.loc[0, 'lines']
'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'

>>> df.loc[0, 'lines2']
<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7fa386735a30>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It answers the question as it was posed. And you are right, ```'LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))'``` is not a valid wkt and it is not what I have in my df. It is actually, ```'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'```.

Comment: But, I still cannot get from ```'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2)'``` to ```LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])```. Basically, I want to convert the entire column of the first type into the other.